Send number[][] as an input to post method, angular -> spring boot
I am creating a form to retrieve number of ancestors
<form #ancestorForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getAncestorsOnInput(ancestorForm.value)">

    <label></label>
    N elements
    <input type="text" name="n" ngModel>
    Child to parent
    <input type="text" name="edges" ngModel>
    <input type="submit">

</form>

here is my service
getAncestorsOnInput(values: {n: number, edges: number[][]}) {
console.log(values);
 this.helloService.getAncestorsOfNumbers(values).subscribe(
   (ancestors) => {
     this.ancestors = ancestors;
  }
 )

}
I cant seem to figure out how to convert the edges from an input like this
[0,3], [0,4], [1,3], [2,4], [2,7], [3,5], [3,6], [3,7], [4,6]

and break it up into a number array, as it comes as a string, how can I do this?
Thank you.

Assuming the arriving string looks like:
"0.3;0.4;1.3;2.4;2.7;3.5;3.6;3.7;4.6"
You can do something like this:
(ancestors) => {
      this.ancestors = ancestors.split(";")
                                  .map(
                                    edges=>edges.split(",")
                                      .map(num=>Number(num))
                                  );
   }

